# Rails RESTful routes and Facebook's signed_request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, rest

I am creating a Facebook application with Rails and am attempting to stick to RESTful routing. The problem I am having is that Facebook posts a signed_request variable. This causes routes that are not using the POST verb to generate a "No route matches..." error. What is the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Rack middleware like this one:

https://github.com/dekart/facebooker2/blob/master/lib/facebooker2/rack/post_canvas.rb

Answer (score 1):

There is also [Rack::Facebook::MethodFix](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/rack-facebook-methodfix) middleware. It provides optional validation of `signed_request` parameter. You can also set it to ignore some URL's.

```
# Basic usage
use Rack::Facebook::MethodFix

# Validate signed_request
use Rack::Facebook::MethodFix, :secret_id => "c561df165eacdd6e32672c9eaee10318"

# Do not apply request method fix to admin urls.
use Rack::Facebook::MethodFix, :exclude => proc { |env| env["PATH_INFO"].match(/^\/admin/) }
```